# Why does 'jobs' always return a line for finished processes when run in a subshell within a script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, jobs

Normally, when a job is launched in the background, `jobs` will report that it is finished the first time it is run after the job's completion, and nothing for subsequent executions:

```
$ ping -c 4 localhost &>/dev/null &
[1] 9666
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ping -c 4 localhost &> /dev/null &
$ jobs
[1]+  Done                    ping -c 4 localhost &> /dev/null
$ jobs  ## returns nothing
$
```

However, when run in a subshell within a script it seems to always return a value. This script will never exit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ping -c 3 localhost &>/dev/null &
while [[ -n $(jobs) ]]; do
    sleep 1; 
done
```

If I use `tee` in the `[[ ]]` construct to see the output of `jobs`, I see that it is always printing the `Done ...` line. Not only once as I expected but, apparently, for ever.

What is even stranger is that running `jobs` within the loop causes it to exit as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ping -c 3 localhost &>/dev/null &
while [[ -n $(jobs) ]]; do
    jobs
    sleep 1; 
done
```

Finally, as pointed out by @mury, the first script works as expected and exits if run from the commandline:

```
$ ping -c 5 localhost &>/dev/null & 
[1] 13703
$ while [[ -n $(jobs) ]]; do echo -n . ; sleep 1; done
...[1]+  Done                    ping -c 5 localhost &> /dev/null
$
```

This came up when I was answering a [question](https://superuser.com/q/893144/151431) on Super User so please don't post answers recommending better ways of doing what that loop does. I can think of a few myself. What I am curious about is

1. Why does `jobs` act differently within the `[[ ]]` construct? Why will it always return the `Done...` line while it doesn't when run manually?
2. Why does running `jobs` within the loop change the behavior of the script?

Comment: It's not the subshell that does this, but being run in a script. When I ran `while [[ -n $(jobs) ]] ..` in an interactive shell, it worked fine.

Comment: @muru thanks, I'll clarify that, but the question still stands. Why does it behave this way when run in a script and why does including `jobs` in the loop fix it? Also, it works as expected even in a script if it is not run in a subshell. If you save the output in a variable and test that variable, for example.

Comment: @iyrin as I pointed out in the question, I am not looking for solutions. I can think of several ways to do this better. I am trying to understand the workings of `jobs` and why it behaves this way in this setting.

Answer (score 6):

You know, of course, that `$(…)` causes the command(s) within the parentheses
to run in a subshell.  And you know, of course, that `jobs` is a shell builtin. 
Well, it looks like `jobs` clears a job from the shell’s memory
once its death *has been reported*. 
But, when you run `$(jobs)`, the `jobs` command runs in a subshell,
so it doesn’t get a chance to tell the parent shell
(the one that’s running the script) that the death of the background job
(`ping`, in your example) has been reported. 
So, each time the shell spawns a subshell to run the `$(jobs)` thingie,
that subshell still has a complete list of jobs
(i.e., the `ping` job is there, even though it’s dead after the 5th iteration),
and so `jobs` still (again) believes that
it needs to report on the status of the `ping` job
(even if it’s been dead for the past four seconds).

This explains why running an unadulterated `jobs` command
within the loop causes it to exit as expected:
once you run `jobs` *in the parent shell*, the parent shell knows that
the job’s termination *has been reported* to the user.

Why is it different in the interactive shell? 
Because, whenever a foreground child of an interactive shell terminates,
the shell reports on any background jobs that have terminated<sup>1</sup>
while the foreground process was running. 
So, the `ping` terminates while the `sleep 1` is running,
and when the `sleep` terminates,
the shell reports on the background job’s death. 
Et voilà.

---

<sup>1</sup> It might be more accurate to say “any background jobs
that have changed state while the foreground process was running.” 
I believe that it might also report on jobs that have been suspended
(`kill -SUSP`, the programmatic equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)
or become unsuspended (`kill -CONT`, which is what the `fg` command does).

Comment: OK, this is helping me understand. However, I don't get how the `jobs` run within the while loop will affect the `$(jobs)`. By your reasoning, the `$(jobs)` shouldn't have access to the information of the parent shell.  Why does running `jobs` within the loop affect that? Is there some sort of central repository where bash saves the running jobs and that is only updated when run outside a subshell? Isn't the loop running in its own subshell anyway?

Comment: Because running `jobs` directly in the shell that's running the script (the "parent shell") changes the information in the parent shell's memory. And _subsequent_ invocations of `$(jobs)` are effected by a fork (and _not_ an exec) of that parent shell, resulting in a child shell process that has a copy of the parent shell's memory at the time of the fork.

Comment: @terdon The loop is not running in the subshell. `$(jobs)` creates a subshell just to run the `jobs` built-in command. That subshell replicates the main bash process at the time it's started, i.e. each time it's starting to execute `[[ -n $(jobs) ]]`.